How to pass a value from a nextjs route to an actual component
Ok so i was trying to create a nextjs project and after some problems with the database i connected to the one hosted by vercell. I actually did use some routes to insert or select some information into the database so i tried to use this new information to develop my app even further. I wanted to add a dynamic react component that appears only if the username of whom logged in is saved in local storage. After some research i did find an option, but local storage does not save data and i dont know why.
Ok so i tried:
from the route component to save the data in local storage with different methods but it does say localstorage is not defined so i tryed these options:
This is the route.js code:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres";

export async function POST(req) {
    const body = await req.json();
    const { username, password } = body;
    const resultat=await sql'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=${username} 
    AND passwordhash=${password}'
    
    if(resultat.rows.length===0){
        console.log("Authentification failed");
        return NextResponse.json({ error:"Invalid credentials" }, { status: 404 });
    }
    if(username==resultat.rows[0].username && 
        password==resultat.rows[0].passwordhash){
        console.log("Merge autentificarea")
        try{
        localStorage.setItem("username",username) || ""
        localStorage.setItem("password",password) || ""
        console.log("Am salvat datele");}
        catch (error){ }

        return NextResponse.json({ message: "Logged In" },{ status:200 });
        }
    return NextResponse.json({ error:"Invalid credentials" }, { status: 404 });
}

But the console did not return back. Then while using the page that uses the route:
"use client"
import './LoginForm.css';
import Button from '../Button';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

const LoginForm = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const onClickHandle = async () => {
    console.log('Username:', username);

    let res=await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    });

    let data=await res.json();
    if(data.status === 200) {
      localStorage.setItem("auth", true);
      localStorage.setItem("username", username);
      console.log(username)
      router.push('/');
  }
    else{
      console.error("Login failed",data.error)
    }
  
  }

  
  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <form className="login-form">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="username"
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Link href="/"><Button onClick={onClickHandle}>Log In</Button></Link>
          
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;

and then in the component i want the username to be used:
"use client"
import React from 'react';
import "./Navbar.css"
import Button from './Button';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Navbar(){
        const [username,setUsername]=useState("");
        useEffect(()=>{
        if(typeof window!=="undefined"){
                if(localStorage.getItem("username")===null)
                    {
                        console.log("there is nothing here")
                    }    
                const auth = localStorage.getItem("auth");
                if(auth){
                const storedUserName = localStorage.getItem("username");
                setUsername(storedUserName);
                }
        }
        },[])

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="container">
            <ul className="nav-links">
            <li>
                <Link href="/">
                        <Button>Home</Button>
                </Link>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
                <Link href='/categories'><Button>Categorii</Button></Link>
                
        </div>
        <div>
                <Link href="/newreleases"><Button>New Releases</Button></Link>
        </div>
        <div>
                <Link href='/search'><Button>Search</Button></Link>
        </div>
        <div>   
                <Link href='/login'><Button>Log In</Button></Link>
        </div>
        { username &&(
                <div>
                        <Link href='/'><Button>{username}</Button></Link>
                </div>
        )}
    </nav>
  )
}

I really dont know how to pass the pass the information in any other way.

Try to add another statement to your if, wait for the localStorage to be present and test it out.

I'd also suggest to try to separate the steps, like try to test the db connection within and the go back to the getting the data into the comp and using the post function etc

You're writing to localStorage in an API route, which runs on the server (EG, on Vercel, in a node runtime), not in the user's browser.  Then you try to read it in the component, which is running in the browser.  So, that's not going to work.

@TheoOliveira It does connect to the database now, but it does not want to save those variables in localstorage

@MattMorgan am i not saving the data after i receive the response back from the route? i mean i hope that is what i am trying to do in that page.js

i didnt pay attentoin to the post request, like @MattMorgan said. the instance you are trying to active is that your are on server-side trying to save things on the browser which is client side.

Two things:

You're trying to save the response from the database call in localstorage within the API route, which runs on the server, then read it in the component, which is rendered on the client browser, so that won't work.
You're getting the username from the database, but then you should return it  as part of the API response.

As a side note: don't store your client's password anywhere but in the database, and even then it should be encrypted.  Don't return it from the API response, and definitely don't write it to localstorage.
Instead, you should return the response from your API endpoint, and use that  response to set localstorage in the login form component.  Something like this:
// in API route, success case:
return NextResponse.json({ auth: true, username}, {status: 200});

Incidentally, there's nothing about setting localstorage that's going to make the useEffect in your Navbar component run, so even once you get the username set in localstorage, that component won't show it.  You need to pass the username (or the auth status) to the Navbar as a prop.  But that's worthy of a separate question.
